# CQL select specific columns

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

For the following `Cassandra` schema:

```
CREATE TABLE periods (
period_name text,
event_name text,
event_date timestamp,
weak_race text,
strong_race text,
PRIMARY KEY (period_name, event_name, event_date)
);
```

Usually the `select` statement can be like:

```
SELECT * FROM ruling_stewards
WHERE king = 'Brego'
AND reign_start >= 2450
AND reign_start < 2500 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

But is there a way to select the specific columns without giving a relation? For example, to show all the `event_name` and `period_name` columns? (do not show other unmentioned columns).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as with SQL, to only show specific columns, you can name them in your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT event_name, period_name 
FROM ruling_stewards;
```

That works with or without specifying a `WHERE` clause.

For further reference, read through the Cassandra 2.x [SELECT](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html) doc.